# Text field Layout in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

If I enter some input (without pressing enter key) in "description" field and raise an Incident.
After creation, when I open this Incident, all the input entered in "description" field is displayed horizontally in one single line and all the form is messed up with this description field.
This is a text field and does not wrap the text automatically. Moreover, this is happening in 'Default' view only. I investigated, but do not find a clue how it is happening.

Anybody, please assist...

Answer (score 0):

The description field in any of the forms like incident or change or problem has an id in HTML behind

for incident its : "`incident.description`"
for change its   : "`change_request.description`"
for problem its  : "`problem.description`"

and so on.

If you want the size of the description text area to be constant, and have an admin or developer access then, add a "client script" for each form like this.

```
function onLoad() {


var id=document.getElementById("incident.description");//change the value as per the form.
id.style.resize="none";

}
```

This will do the job.
All the best.

Comment: The problem faced by @user1934643 was existing till Berlin release. The problem has been fixed in the next versions i.e. Calgary, Dublin etc